# Rails: Query on a Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `Airport` model with a `country` column and a `#region` method.

`Airport.where(country:"United States")`, querying a column, returns a nice useable "array" of AR objects, of class `Airport::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

However:

```
Airport.where(region: nil)      
  Airport Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "airports".* FROM "airports" WHERE "airports"."region" IS NULL                                                                                              
=> #<Airport::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fecc5d319f8>
```

Which is of the same class, but is pretty much a "sealed box" that I can't call `#count` or `#first` or anything on.

I can get the "correct array" using `select` but then my console spits out a zillion SQL queries instead of one.

How do I get the data I want as an accessible array?

Comment: What is the data that you want? Also you should consider creating a normalization table for countries instead of repeating the names all over your Airports table. Its much better to have a table with 195 ish rows vs thousands of duplicate strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord is solely responsible for getting information from the database for you - and because `region` is a method on the `Airport` model, and not a database column, you don't get the result you expect. This is easily seen in the generated SQL statement for your query - it's looking for a column called `region`:

```sql
SELECT "airports".* FROM "airports" WHERE "airports"."region" IS NULL
```

Your intuition about `select` being the proper way to do this is correct. Using `select` shouldn't generate a bundle of SQL queries. Try:

```ruby
Airport.all.select { |a| a.region.nil? }
```

And check out the generated SQL. You should see something like:

```sql
Airport Load (7.1ms)  SELECT "airports".* FROM "airports"
```

That is, unless `#region` has other ActiveRecord queries inside of it, at which point we need to see the method definition to make any other judgements.

Comment: The last thing you said clinches it: Your `select` sample worked, but the `region` method makes queries so that's where they're all coming from.

Comment: COuld you share your region method or better your Airport model?